# usb_serial_init - usb_register failed error with RHEL 7.3, mouse/kb not working

Tags: rhel, boot, usb, keyboard, mouse

I just installed RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.3 on a new system. After booting into the first-boot set up GUI, my keyboard and mouse are not working. They aren't even powered. I saw during the boot process these two errors:

> usbserial: usb_serial_init - usb_register failed
>
> usbserial: usb_serial_init - returning with error -19

I don't know if that's related to my problem. My keyboard/mouse are not connected via a hub, and I tried connecting to different USB ports but they still don't work. Interestingly, they work at the BIOS stage and in the RHEL GUI installer.

How do I fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed RHEL a couple more times, and it finally worked! I don't know why but changing the security policy to something else made USB work.